# building ruby on windows 7

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, installation, nmake

I know this has been asked before but I ran into a specific problem.

I'm trying to build ruby 1.9.2 rc2 on windows 7. When I run configure.bat it aborts with the following message.

```
cl -nologo -MD rtname.c user32.lib -link > nul
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I find that the file 'rtname.c' does not exist anywhere within the source files. And this is why cl aborts.

I'm totally clueless as to what to do next. Searching for rtname.c on google doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'd ping ruby core. It "should" build with MSVC...

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to do on windows is make sure your have some version of Visual studio C++ express edition installed. The latest version can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)

Next, you need to run the following file from the command line:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`

This configures your path environmental variable to allow the command prompt (and other programs) to find cl.exe. After doing this, running configure.bat should work correctly. This will build a 32-bit version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Visual Studio is required in your case to build Ruby from sources on Windows, but why don't you use [RubyInstaller](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller) instead? It is a nice build environment; you can compile any version of Ruby on your machine, even from TRUNK.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you must have the C++ compiler installed to build Ruby. Could it be that you are missing that?

The [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) is quite stable and works most times.

Answer (score 0):

I found that having already installed ruby on the box helps, see http://blog.cyplo.net/2011/01/01/compiling-ruby-1-9-2-windows/ , hope that helps